# localising a string in en.yml, translation missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I want to localise a string in my code but the path I'm putting in en.yml isn't doing the job. The string is in the file module_list_controller and the line im localising is

```
format.html { redirect_to @module_list, notice: t('.success_message') }
```

where .success_message is what i'm trying to localise. Heres what ive got in en.yml which is wrong, but I think its something similar to this

```
module_lists:
  success_message: "Module successfully created"
```

I know how to localise a string thats in a view, but because this is in a controller I don't know what to write. Thanks.

Solved - the answer i was looking for was

```
module_list:
 create:
  success_message: "Module successfully created"
```

and

```
format.html { redirect_to @module_list, notice:t('module_list.create.success_message') }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you should put:

```
module_lists:
  <your action name(create, update...)>:
    success_message: blah
```

Comment: I'm asking what to put in en.yml, ill edit my question to make that a bit clearer